# Microsoft asp.net chart tool does not display the chart on the live server but works fine on my local, how do i solve this?

Tags: charts

I am trying to use the microsoft Charting control on a shared server and have inserted the following:

In my config file i have:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

And in the webpage I have:

Chart1.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;

Chart1.ImageLocation = "~/temporary/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)";

Chart1.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;

on the aspx page:

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" tagprefix="asp" %>

And i also copied the two dll files, 'System.Web.DataVisualization.Design' and 'System.Web.DataVisualization' into my bin folder on the live server.

This only generates a blank chart with only the title but on my local host it shows the graph with the title.

Please help as i am very stuck and I'm getting frustrated that this doesnt work.  If no one can solve this is there any other free graphing tools that are just as good or even better in order for me to replace the microsoft asp charting tool?

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, try to improve your answers' formatting. For example, put 4 spaces before each line of code. Thanks! See more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Same problem. Read a gazillion articles. Still not resolved. Did you ever manage to get to the bottom of it. And I've not found any other free tool that are as good or without conditions/restrictions